# Is it obligatory to shave the head when doing Hajj?

Tags: hajj, hair

I have shoulder length hair.
Is it obligatory to get my head shaved bald?

The reason I ask is because of this verse who says one shouldn't shave the head until the offering is done:

> ... وَلَا تَحْلِقُوا رُءُوسَكُمْ حَتَّىٰ يَبْلُغَ الْهَدْيُ مَحِلَّهُ ...
>
> ... And do not shave your heads until the sacrificial animal has reached its place of slaughter. ...
>
> Quran 2:196

**Question:** Is it obligatory to shave the head when doing Hajj?

*As a bonus, if it is obligatory, would it always be obligatory to shave the head or would it only be the first time doing hajj, or every single time?*

Answer (score 3):

Cutting hair on the head is an obligatory ritual of Hajj:

> ولا **تحلقو**ا رءوسكم حتى يبلغ الهدي محله
>
> And do not **shave** your heads until the sacrificial animal has
> reached its place of slaughter.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:196](https://quran.com/2/196)</sup>

> لتدخلن المسجد الحرام ان شاء الله امنين **محلقين** رءوسكم و**مقصرين**
> لا تخافون
>
> You will surely enter al-Masjid al-Haram, if Allah wills, in safety,
> with your heads **shaved** and [hair] **shortened**, not fearing
> [anyone].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 48:27](https://quran.com/48/27)</sup>

> قال لما قدم النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم مكة امر اصحابه ان يطوفوا بالبيت،
> وبالصفا والمروة، ثم يحلوا، **ويحلقوا او يقصروا‏**
>
> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>
> When the Prophet (ﷺ) came to Mecca, he ordered his Companions to
> perform Tawaf round the Ka`ba and between Safa and Marwa, to finish
> their Ihram and get their **hair shaved off or cut short**.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari, Book of Hajj](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/209)</sup>

For men, shaving it completely is the Sunnah and the preferable thing to do, though trimming it short is also permissible.

> قال **حلق** النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وطايفة من اصحابه، **وقصر بعضهم‏**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) and some of his companions got their heads **shaved**
> and some **others got their hair cut short**.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari, Book of
> Hajj](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/207)</sup>

> ان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ‏"‏ اللهم ارحم **المحلقين**
> ‏"‏‏.‏ قالوا والمقصرين يا رسول الله قال ‏"‏ اللهم ارحم المحلقين ‏"‏‏.‏
> قالوا والمقصرين يا رسول الله قال ‏"‏ و**المقصرين** ‏"‏‏.‏ وقال الليث
> حدثني نافع ‏"‏ رحم الله المحلقين ‏"‏ مرة او مرتين‏.‏ قال وقال عبيد
> الله حدثني نافع وقال في الرابعة ‏"‏ والمقصرين
>
> Narrated Abdullah bin `Umar:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O Allah! Be merciful to those who have
> their **head shaved**."
>
> The people said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! And (invoke Allah for)
> those who get their hair cut short."
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "O Allah! Be merciful to those who have their
> head shaved."
>
> The people said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! And those who get their
> hair cut short."
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said (the third time), "And to those who **get their
> hair cut short**."
>
> Nafi said that the Prophet (ﷺ) had said once or twice, "O Allah! Be
> merciful to those who get their head shaved," and on the fourth time
> he added, "And to those who have their hair cut short."
>
> — [Sahih Bukhari, Book of Hajj](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/25/205)

If you decide to only trim the hair, then it should be shortened at minimum by the length of your fingertip.

---

Cutting hair is required, be it the first Hajj or a repeated one. There is a view that shaving (rather than trimming) is obligatory on the first Hajj but this isn't mainstream.

From [Mughni](https://shamela.ws/book/8463/1345):

> إلا أنه يروى عن الحسن ، أنه كان يوجب الحلق في أول حجة حجها . ولا يصح
> هذا ; لأن الله تعالى قال : محلقين رءوسكم ومقصرين
>
> [My own translation so take care]
>
> ... the exception narrated from Hassan (Basri?) that it is wajib to shave the head on the
> first hajj. However this is not correct since Allah said:
> *heads shaved and hair shortened* [48:27](https://quran.com/48/27)

From [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya196.html):

> وأجمع أهل العلم على أن التقصير يجزئ عن الرجال ، إلا شيء ذكر عن الحسن
> أنه كان يوجب الحلق في أول حجة يحجها الإنسان
>
> [My own translation so take care]
>
> It is the consensus of the people of knowledge that trimming hair is
> permissible for men, except for what was mentioned from Hassan who
> said that in the first Hajj that a person performs, it is obligatory
> to shave the head.